# SqlAlchemy - create_engine takes long time

Tags: python, aws-lambda, sqlalchemy

I am working with sqlalchemy and trying to connect to a RDS server on AWS (MySql), I am receiving pretty slow create_engine times during the startup of my program.

The connection times are around 3 seconds - when I run it on a local server its almost immediate.

3 seconds seems like a pretty long time, Is this normal? Are there any parameters I can add to make this faster?

Thanks.

Comment: You're supplying some FQDN -- what is that domain name? It might have multiple AAAA or A records, and you're timing out on a subset of them, or failing over from IPv6 to IPv4.

Comment: I seem to have the same issue, for me it's more like 5-6 seconds whereas with prisma it's like 2-3 seconds. (Additional delay in mine could be cuz of roundtrip latency, but it's still consistently slow compared to prisma). I also tried with a fresh RDS instance with no overloaded connections.